# PHP remove commas from numeric strings

Tags: php, string, replace, numbers

In PHP, I have an array of variables that are ALL strings.  Some of the values stored are numeric strings with commas.

What I need:

A way to trim the commas from strings, and ONLY do this for numeric strings.  This isn't as straightforward as it looks.  The main reason is that the following fails:

```
$a = "1,435";

if(is_numeric($a))
    $a = str_replace(',', '', $a);
```

This fails because `$a = "1435"` is numeric.  But `$a = "1,435"` is not numeric.  Because some of the strings I get will be regular sentences with commas, I can't run a string replace on every string.

Comment: use preg_replace to selectively replace commas that are enclosed on both sides by [0-9]?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not tested, but probably something like `if(preg_match("/^[0-9,]+$/", $a)) $a = str_replace(...)`

Comment: Yes, this works.  I tried all the string formats I would expect, and this works.  Will mark as accepted answer once the site lets me.

Comment: If you want to remove commas from numbers inside a string that also contains words use this pattern if you want to avoid removing commas in words: /[0-9]+[,]+[0-9]+/

Comment: This answer is not elegant.  Why would you all `preg_match()` then `str_replace()` when it can be done with `preg_replace()` alone?

Answer (score 126):

Do it the other way around:

```
$a = "1,435";
$b = str_replace( ',', '', $a );

if( is_numeric( $b ) ) {
    $a = $b;
}
```

Comment: potential overhead of calling `str_replace` every time, but the absence of any regex is a big plus.

Answer (score 30):

The easiest would be:

```
$var = intval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $var));
```

or if you need float:

```
$var = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $var));
```

Comment: You have forgotten the possibility of negative numbers. You'll need to add the -
$var = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.\-]/', '', $var));

Comment: The dot and they hyphen do not need to be escaped in the character class.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like the ideal solution for what you're looking for is `filter_var()`:

```
$a = filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
```

(Note that it's using FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT instead of FILTER_VALIDATE_INT because that one doesn't currently have a FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND option).

Answer (score 7):

Try this .this worked for me

`number_format(1235.369,2,'.','')`

if you use  number_format like this 
`number_format(1235.369,2)` answer will be *1,235.37*

but if you use like below

`number_format(1235.369,2,'.','')` answer will be *1235.37*

it's removing the "," of "1,235.37"

Comment: Works! But the question is about removing commas from **existing numeric strings** and not to format it on **any numeric value**. If you try `number_format('1,235.369',2,'.','')`, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function cleanData($a) {

     if(is_numeric($a)) {

     $a = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/s', '', $a);
     }

     return $a;

}
```

Comment: The OP has stated that `$a = "1,435" is not numeric`.  So this answer will fail.  This answer is also low value because there is no explanation of how it works or why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove commas from numbers inside a string that *also* contains words, the easiest way I think would be to use *preg_replace_callback*:

Example:

> `$str = "Hey hello, I've got 12,500 kudos for you, spend it well"`

```
function cleannr($matches)
{
    return str_replace("," , "" , $matches["nrs"]);
}

$str = preg_replace_callback ("/(?P<nrs>[0-9]+,[0-9]+)/" , "cleannr" , $str);
```

Output:

> "Hey hello, I've got 12500 kudos for you, spend it well"

In this case the pattern (regex) differs from the one given in the accepted answer since we don't want to remove the other commas (punctuation).

If we'd use `/[0-9,]+/` here instead of `/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/` the output would be:

> "Hey hello I've got 12500 kudos for you spend it well"

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
/**
 * This will parse the money string
 * 
 * For example 1, 234, 456.00 will be converted to 123456.00
 * 
 * @return 
 */
function parseMoney(string $money) : float
{
    $money = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '', $money);
    return number_format((float) $money, 2, '.', '');
}
```

Example;

```
parseMoney('-1, 100,   000.01'); //-1100000.01
```